# Clang preprocessor to strip comments from C++ files

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

I know the gcc preprocessor can use -fpreprocessed to only remove comments from a file and leave the rest untouched but how can I do the same with clang?

Comment: You want your file preprocessed? You can use GNU, but it loses all the formatting.  You want the formatted file without comments?  Why?

Comment: i have two directories that have the same project only one is slightly newer version.  most of the changesbare comments and some formatting.  i need to find out which files have functionally significant changes. this is a problem that will be coming up in the next months and also i am curious how to solve this with clang

Comment: Well, you could preprocess *both* files and then strip the #line directives.   Alternatively you could solve it another way.  See our SmartDifferencer, which compares two source files but ignores formatting and comments, and other non-semantic differences.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer.

Comment: didnt know about that on thnx!

Answer (score 2):

As [decribed here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html), use -E (and probably -P, to exclude line number info)

```
clang -E -P <inputfile> -o <outputfile>
```

(although this will do more than just remove comments - it'll also expand macros etc...)